# Regex That allows # and + sign

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using the following in my c# code

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"\b[\w]*\b");
```

I need to enable the regex to allow the # or + characters as it is trying to find programming languages in the input string.  Therefore C# or C++ are getting ignored.

I've tried

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"\b[\w+\$\#\+']*\b");
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"\b[a-zA-Z0-9@#$%&*+\-]*\b");

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"\b[a-zA-Z0-9\#\+]*\b");
```

but none of the above seem to work.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about whitespace boundaries, `(?<!\S)\w+[+#]*(?!\S)`? How can you describe a *word* in your case? What  are the contexts that define *word* boundaries here?

Comment: Note that `\b[\w]*\b` matches all word boundary's

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is almost fine but you can't have `\b` at the end of regex as `+` and `#` characters are not part of word character and their appearance will already break the word boundary. So boundary can be applied conditionally and your correct regex should become this,

```
\b[\w+#]*(?:\b|(?<=[+#]))
```

Which will successfully match,

```
c
c++
c#
Java
Python++
```

But it won't match ++c which I don't think you want to match which is why I haven't removed `\b` from the beginning of regex.

In case you want to match `++c` then your regex will become,

```
[\w+#]*(?:\b|(?<=[+#]))
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zosEMK/2)**

Comment: This is good but it’s less strict than OP’s regex due to the missing final word boundary; you can re-enable it by adding a alternation between `\b` and a zero-length lookbehind for `#` and `+` (`\b[\w+#]+(?:\b|(?<=[+#]))`).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I agree and it's a good suggestion. If the characters at the end are non-word characters, then it makes sense to check that using lookahead and apply the boundary condition conditionally.